# How do I convert this line of code to swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, quickblox

I am a new programmer. I started learning swift 2.0 without objective c, which I guess was a mistake.

I am trying to integrate quickblox into my swift app, however this line of code is really confusing me. I was wondering if someone could give me a hand

```
- (void (^)(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user))successBlock
{
    return ^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
        // Login succeeded
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returns a block function, which gets two parameters: the response and the user. Its return type is void.

So in swift, it should basically look like this:

```
func successBlock() -> (QBResponse, QBUUser) -> Void {
    return { (response, user) in
        //Login succeeded.
    }
}
```

It could also be converted to a computed property as it does not have side effects and does not rely on any parameters:

```
var successBlock: (QBResponse, QBUUser) -> Void {
    return { (response, user) in
        //Login succeeded.
    }
}
```